# Rllib OfflineData preparation for SAC

Tags: python, ray, rllib

I have some offline experiences: (s, a, r, s') that were generated with a heuristic. And I want to use these when training SAC agents. Using the example [saving_experiences](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/rllib/examples/saving_experiences.py) to prepare my data gives me an error when using with SAC. Here is a [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1JEV8v1We7MOui12lBT2Y_hBUuc8nE6iz?usp=sharing) where the issue is exposed for the pendulum-v0 environment.
What I understand from the error message is that SAC is expecting some 'weights' (and some time 't'?!) beside the experiences that were generated as offline data.
Can I use just the offline experiences (s, a, r, s') with SAC?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the `saving_experiences` file you shared, it looks like when you load these offline experiences into `rllib`, it creates `SampleBatch` objects, which is how data is presented to agents (at least for off-policy agents) when they are trained with gradient methods.

The "weights" refer to the priority weights of the samples, and would be used for Importance Sampling-weighted Prioritized Experience Replay (check out the `PrioritzedReplayBuffer` class [here](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/rllib/execution/replay_buffer.py) if interested).  You should be able to just set these all to `1.0` if you don't care too much about weighting them.

You should be able to use offline experiences with just `(s, a, r, s')` with SAC, however, you may need to format your data into an appropriate `SampleBatch`, e.g. with the code fragment below:

```
from ray.rllib.policy.sample_batch import SampleBatch, MultiAgentBatch

# Initialize SampleBatch
rllib_batch_dict = {"obs": s, "actions": a, "rewards": r, "new_obs": s`,
                    "dones": np.array([False for i in range(len(s))], 
                    "weights": np.ones((len(s)), "eps_id": episode_ids,
                    "unroll_id": episode_steps, "agent_index": np.zeros(len(s))}  # Where your data is stored in (s, a, r, s`)

# Wrap your dictionary in a SampleBatch wrapper
rllib_batch = SampleBatch(rllib_batch_dict)

# If you still get errors, try wrapping this in a MultiAgentSampleBatch
marl_batch_dict = {"0": rllib_batch}
marl_batch = MultiAgentSampleBatch(marl_batch_dict)
```

For "t", I think this is just the time step for the sample in the episode, e.g. 0 if it is the first step, 1 if it is the second, and so on.  Perhaps you could just keep track of this as you create your `(s, a, r, s` )` data?

Finally, not sure if you need this, but you can also try creating a `SampleBatch` manually, and then wrapping this in a `MultiAgentSampleBatch` if need be.  To do that, you'll just need to follow the code above, and then add in the following key/value pairs before creating the `SampleBatch` object (which is really just a dictionary wrapper):

1. `'obs'` --> `s`
2. `'actions'` --> `a`
3. `rewards` --> `r`
4. `'new_obs'` --> `s'`
5. `'dones'` --> set these to whether the timestep marks the end of an episode
6. `'agent_index'` --> 0 (if single-agent, else you'll need to index)
7. `'eps_id'` --> This is a placeholder episode ID (I don't think it's ever used during training), could set to `"0"`, `"1"` etc.
8. `'unroll_id'` --> This is the step number, e.g. `0`, `1`, etc.
9. `'weights'` --> These are the weights for importance sampling.  If you don't care about this you could just set them to `1.0`.

Hope this helps - good luck!